# magento 2 order page error

Tags: magento2

when I am going to create order and in payment/review page.
give error message "An error occurred on the server. please try to place order again"
please look image also
[image]

Comment: Could yo check your web inspector to see if the XHR request that is fired returns some more information? Also: do you have any 3rd party modules installed that might touch the checkout? (like shipping- or payment methods)

Comment: XHR request showing in Herader: Status Code: 400 Bad Request....and response{"message":"An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again."}

Comment: And I have not using any 3rd party module. because i have migrate magento 1.9.2.2 fresh version in magento 2.2.2

Comment: Any more information in the logs?

Comment: I have done there is one filed not in order table.:)